# Drive with vs ride with

Tags: past-tense

Can we say Toni rode with/drove with Danny to the mall? 
I am not sure if "rode with" gives the same meaning of "drove with".

I want to say that Toni went in the car with Danny, and he drives her to the mall along with him because he was already driving to the mall. I am not sure if saying "drive with someone or ride with someone" means to get into the car with them.

Is it correct to say that "Danny drove Toni to the mall with him." to indicate that he was also going to the same destination, or I should only say that "Danny drove Toni to the mall"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think both are grammatically correct, however they give slightly different meanings.

- "Toni drove with Danny to the mall." This shows that Toni went in a car with Danny, and Danny drove them both to the mall.
- "Toni rode with Danny to the mall". I think this could both mean they both took a car together, or even they both shared a bike to get to the mall. So I would suggest, to avoid confusion, that you said "Toni got a ride with Danny to the mall", as this suggests that he got a lift in his car.

Comment: In British English, "Toni rode with Danny to the mall" would strongly suggest they were on a bike or bikes (motor or pedal). We don't use "ride" very much for travelling by car.

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming Danny and Toni are using a single car as transportation:*

Either of the two is acceptable. One can drive with another, and one can ride with another. Be aware that *most* people consider " A rode with B" to exclude the possibility that A was the one driving, but "A drove with B" leaves open the possibility that A or B (or neither) was driving the vehicule. "riding" doesn't convey the same sense of operation of the transport vehicule. So, if Danny was behind the wheel (driving) with Toni as his passenger, **"Danny drove with Toni"**, "Toni rode with Danny", and "Toni drove with Danny" are the best options, probably in that order. "Danny rode with Toni", though, is best avoided.

Also, it's possible to be more specific as to who was driving, via direct objects. As an example, "**Danny drove Toni** to the mall" clearly states that Danny was driving and Toni was his passenger; Toni is receiving the action, being driven.